# MacBook pro stuck in a loop after booting

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

yesterday i turned off my computer as usual nothing strange yet ive noticed that it get so hot lately ( I figured out later that it’s due to dirt in fan , i cleaned it ) ; then today morning computer stucked in a black loop after apple logo , it shows in a half second cursor then it turn. Black again , i tried safe mode ( stucked in same loop )and repairing disk and reinstalling macos i tried alt command R+P and nothing worked , i didnt install anything yesterday yet i ignored an update from apple from last week ; im using sierra , i need help please , and thank you so much in advance

Comment: Can you get into [Recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)? Was autologin enabled? If so, [the "resetpassword" command typed into Terminal may help you](http://www.needhelp4mac.com/2013/11/use-os-x-recovery-disk-assistant-to-reset-your-files-and-folder-permissions/). Disregard the part about Recovery Disk (unless your Mac is that old). You may have some cleaning up for the user account.

Comment: BTW, you have to launch Terminal from the Utilities menu once you get into Recovery mode.

Comment: Thank you trellis for you answers yes i got into recovery mode and i reset password but nothing changed

Comment: Was autologin enabled?

Comment: how old is the computer? do you have a hard disk or an SSD? If you have a hard disk, and it's old, then it's possibly (probably?) dying. Replace it, migrate from the old disk to the new, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Trellis I really dont know if its enabled or not ,

Comment: Zonker , yeah i think its old , its macbook pro 2012 , 13 inches i7 8 ram

Comment: But when i use disk utility it shows that the h hard drive works just fine , i wonder if some sort of sata cable damaged or something like that

Comment: This could be anything from a corrupted boot image to a failed GPU (common in these models).  I would start with [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.  Next try installing a clean version of macOS onto an **external** drive (just for testing).  If the problem goes away, it has to do with what's on your drive.  If not, the problem is your logic board.

Comment: Thanks alan , idid hardware test again and it says no trouble founded.

Comment: Install on an external drive as described and try booting from that.  Post the results.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the OS might corrupt hence failing to boot, you can verify this by booting up using verbose mode to see where it gets stuck at.

To fix the actual issue I think you should boot into recovery mode and do a re-install of the OS (formally called Archive install) 
This shouldn't delete any data but if you had a backup then good. Here are instructions

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204904

Comment: Hi maximus thank you for you answer , i boot in recovery mood i tried to install using command r nothing happened and option command r after installation done it shows a apple logo and a wheel and it stucked there , i tried shift option command r to install lion back but it says that my hard drive has lastest version ...